# Is there a performance impact for using GraphQL fragments with the Public Content API?

Tags: graphql

We can create a reusable parts of a GraphQL query using a fragment as seen in the following example.

```
fragment Fields on Component {
  itemId
  title
  content {
    ... on UntypedContent {
      data
      type
    } 
  }
}
{
  pagequery: page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 7, pageId: 726 ) {
    itemId
    title
    url
    regions {
      name
      components {
        title
        ... on Component {
          ...Fields
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see that this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/graphql-fragments-explained/) notes that GraphQL clients can make use of fragments for caching options.

**Is there a performance impact of using fragments in calls to the Content Delivery Public Content API?**

In other words when the above query is made, is the "...Fields" fragment sent as part of the same request or does this lead to separate requests/calls to the API?